# SelectList on Razor page model binding error

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I'm trying to follow the example code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start/2.2-stage-samples/RPmovieSearch/Pages/Movies/Index.cshtml), but I must be missing something obvious. Instead of reading my select list options from a data source, I'm just trying to load them in the constructor. But I keep getting the error.

```
InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract, or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Alternatively, set the 'SearchOptions' property to a non-null value.
```

Here's the CS code:

```
public class TestSelectModel : PageModel
{
    private List<SelectListItem> _searchoptions;
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public SelectList SearchOptions { get; set; }
    public TestSelectModel()
    {
        _searchoptions = new List<SelectListItem>();
        _searchoptions.Add(new SelectListItem("By Email", "By Email", true));
        _searchoptions.Add(new SelectListItem("By Request Name", "By Request Name", false));
    }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        SearchOptions = new SelectList(_searchoptions, "Key", "Value", "By Email");

    }
}
```

And here is the cshtml code:

```
<h2>TestSelect</h2>
<form>
    <div>
        <select asp-items="Model.SearchOptions">
            <option value="">Choose an search method</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I have a feeling it is something easy, but I just can't see it.

EDIT

Per comment also tried the code below, which does run the OnGet() function, but it throws `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

```
private List<SelectListItem> _searchoptions;
public SelectList SearchOptions { get; set; }

[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public string BoundSearchField { get; set; }

public TestSelectModel()
{
    _searchoptions = new List<SelectListItem>();
    _searchoptions.Add(new SelectListItem("By Email", "By Email", true));
    _searchoptions.Add(new SelectListItem("By Request Name", "By Request Name", false));
}
public void OnGet()
{
    SearchOptions = new SelectList(_searchoptions, "Key", "Value", "By Email");
}


<form>
    <div>
        <select name="BoundSearchField" asp-items="Model.SearchOptions">
            <option value="">Choose an search method</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Seems like `Model.SearchOptions` is null at render time.  Are you sure the `OnGet()` actually gets called?

Comment: It can't be called because the model binder is trying to create a ```SelectList``` and is throwing an exception because it doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: @DavidTansey I can confirm that the `OnGet()` is not getting called. If I move the `SearchOptions = new SelectList(_searchoptions, "Key", "Value", "By Email");` into the constructor, the select list populates but when I try the `Count()` command it throws `NullReferenceException`. @Jerry I'm sorry but I don't follow your suggestion.

Comment: Actually, I apologize, I should have posted the full code in my answer. There were two things that needed to be changed. `SearchOptions = new SelectList(_searchoptions, "Key", "Value", "By Email");` should actually be `SearchOptions = new SelectList(_searchoptions, "Text", "Value", "By Email");`. I will update my answer for you.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to the original question

> Why am I getting this error `InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Alternatively, set the 'SearchOptions' property to a non-null value`

Is having the `BindProperty` attribute on your `SearchOptions` property will try to bind the header data to your `SelectList`. **Remove the BindPropery attribute from your select list and create a property to receive the selected value.**

The answer to the question in your edit

> Now I'm getting the error `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Is because `"Key"` should be `"Text"`

Change
`SearchOptions = new SelectList(_searchoptions, "Key", "Value", "By Email");`
to `SearchOptions = new SelectList(_searchoptions, "Text", "Value", "By Email");`

Full code:

```
private List<SelectListItem> _searchoptions;

// [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] // Remove this here
public SelectList SearchOptions { get; set; }

// Add a property to receive your selected value
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public string BoundSearchField { get; set; }

public TestSelectModel()
{
    _searchoptions = new List<SelectListItem>();
    _searchoptions.Add(new SelectListItem("By Email", "By Email", true));
    _searchoptions.Add(new SelectListItem("By Request Name", "By Request Name", false));
}
public void OnGet()
{
    // Change "Key" to "Text"
    SearchOptions = new SelectList(_searchoptions, "Text", "Value", "By Email");
}
```

Then add `name="BoundSearchField"` to your .cshtml

```
<form>
    <div>
        <select name="BoundSearchField" asp-items="Model.SearchOptions">
            <option value="">Choose an search method</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This throws the following error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.GetListItemsWithValueField()

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem was with how the `SelectList` and `SelectListItems` were defined. In debug mode they appeared fine but I think the issue was when the render tried to happen. Here is what worked. Note the change were I add the `Text` and `Value` definitions for the items and then copy that when loading the list. Also note that I had to use the bound field to save the user choice after post. I am really curious how that wasn't needed in the [Razor example that I was referencing](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start/2.2-stage-samples/RPmovieSearch/Pages/Movies/Index.cshtml.cs).

```
public TestSelectModel()
{
    _searchoptions = new List<SelectListItem>();
    _searchoptions.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "By Email", Value = "1", Selected = true });
    _searchoptions.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "By Request Name", Value = "2", Selected = false });
}
public void OnGet()
{
    if(BoundSearchField is null)
    {
        BoundSearchField = "1";
    }
    SearchOptions = new SelectList(_searchoptions, "Value", "Text", BoundSearchField);
}
```

Comment: The example you referenced contains `[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] public string MovieGenre { get; set; }` to save the choice after post